# usb powered monitor with vga input?

Tags: usb, display, external-display

i'm looking for a monitor that would be usb powered with a vga input, does this kind of monitor exist?

this would be used for a server(freenas), so i need to be able to look at the boot/bios (this is why i need a vga input) and while being able to look at the OS when booted

my google skill for that seem to give me many result that are NOT usb powered monitor but only monitor with usb powered... (i don't want to plug the monitor in an electric outlet)

Comment: @DavidPostill this is hardware not software?

Comment: Oops. You are correct. 
You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J9XCFOS) may be what you are looking for, the VGA cable is optional but you **may** get by with an HDMI-TO-VGA cable.